# C++ want to add a character inside the box based on x and y from the user. How can I do that?

Tags: visual-c++

E is placed inside the box based on the x nd y got from the user ... In the coding it is referred as xstrt and ystrt. I just need to get another query like the number of elements to be placed inside and get input for different x and y positions and place the element "E". I dont know how it will appear... its just a box of "#". Hope you will understand from the coding itself. This is the first time I'm posting here. kindly tolerate if any mistakes.

current o/p

```
#####
#   #
#   #
#   #
#####
```

desired O/p

```
#####
#   #
# E #
#   #
#####


code:
#include<iostream>

    using namespace std;
    void main()
    {
        int wid, ht; // wid - width and ht - height
        int xstrt, ystrt; // starting point position 
        cout << "Enter height = ";
        cin >> ht;
        cout << "Enter width = ";
        cin >> wid;
        cout << "Enter the start position x and y = ";
        cin >> xstrt, ystrt;
        cout << "\n\n";

        for(int width=1; width<=wid; width++)
        {
            if(width <= 1)
            for(int width=1; width<=wid; width++)
            {
                cout<< "#";
            }
        else if(width<ht)
        {
            cout<< endl;
            for(int width2=1; width2<=wid; width2++)
            {
                 if(width2==1 || width2==wid)
                 cout<< "#";
                 else
                    cout<< " ";
            } //end of for  variable width2
        }// end of else if
        else
        {
            cout<< endl;
for(int width3=1; width3<=wid; width3++)
   {
       cout<<"#";
            }//end of for having variable width3
        }// end of else
    }// end of first for loop
}
```

Comment: A little confused. Does the height and width matter? Do you only need 1 letter 'E' in the middle? What if the user inputs Even height and width? Where does the 'E' go -- upperleft, upperright, lowerleft,lowerright?

Comment: Yes add only letter "E" at different places inside the box. the position is in the same row where # is placed either side.

Comment: Any user checking? width 4 height 4 x 10 y 10

Comment: Want to add a letter say "X" as starting point, and another letter say "Y" as end point all inside the box only. And place a symbol/ character as obstacle and another character as check point. And find the shortest path from starting point to end point through the checkpoint and distance is moved as one step at a time. only top,down,left,right.